# Install Windows 10 after Ubuntu with BIOS trouble

Tags: grub2, partitioning, windows, bios

I got a **huge** virus in Windows, then it collapsed and I accidentally changed the BIOS from UEFI to LEGACY (I couldn't start BIOS in any way).

Then I installed Ubuntu because that was the only way I found to recover my files, but I want to install Windows again along with Ubuntu, the BIOS is lost (I start the USB boot with GRUB2) but when I try to install Windows again in the new partition I created for Windows it says the it couldn't find a new partition (even though I created a new one to add Windows as well).

I'm going mad about this, can you please help me?

Comment: *Update*
I was able to rewrite Windows in Ubuntu partition, still no BIOS, now im stuck in a shitty OS :'(  #imissubuntu

Answer (score 1):

**First Things First**

The BIOS cannot be deleted, otherwise GRUB2 would not load.

Second, My Suggestion is to use GParted on a Live USB version of Ubuntu, and delete **EVERY** partition possible. After that you will need a **Recovery Media** for Windows, and a **Product Key**. If you do not have **Recovery Media**, you can download it from the Microsoft Website, and you will need to have an **extra computer** and a **USB**. If you do not have a **Product Key**, you will need to find it on the bottom of your laptop or on the back of your monitor / computer case.

**In the case that there is an error code, you will need to use google to find the solution.**

Comment: NOTE : You can **ALWAYS** Reinstall Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Use your Ubuntu live installation to back up any files from the windows partitions.(You may need to use the command

> `ntfsfix /dev/*`

where * is the partition that failed to be mounted Then try a clean install of windows(This includes formatting the whole hard drive and re partitioning